# Compilation dependencies between files and the pimple idiom

Tags: c++

I'm reading Effective C++ by Scott Meyers, and I have a question about item 31, "Minimize compilation dependencies between files."

In an example he shows the pimple idiom:

```
#include <string> // standard lib shouldn't be forward-declared

#include <memory>

class PersonImpl;  // Forward decl of Person impl.class

class Date;        // forward decls of classes used in Person interface
class Address;

class Person
{
public:
    Person(const std::string& name, const Date& birthday, const Address& addr);
    std:string name() const;
    std:string birthDate() const;
    std:string address() const;
    ...
private:
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<PersonImpl> pimpl;
};
```

Then he says this:

> Avoid using objects when object references and pointers will do. You
>   may define references and pointers to a type with only a declaration
>   for the type. Defining objects of a type necessitates the presence of
>   the type's definition.

Is there ever a time when you *can't* use references or pointers? Couldn't you use the pimple idiom for *all* classes you design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some context require complete types. E.g: when you'd like to store object by value in a vector:

```
std::vector<Person> persons; // Person must be complete
```

You can't use a reference here, and suppose you'd like to avoid having empty persons (= nullptr).

Please note, as far as I can tell, nowadays the pimpl idiom is avoided because of the added complexity, performance and storage penalty.

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't think of templates. The performance penalty is from allocating on the heap as apposed to the stack, right?

Comment: Performance penalty: yes. Regarding complexity: it's so frustrating when you open a file, and all the class members are just forwarding the arguments. (Or are they?)

Comment: I agree, it sounded a bit overly complex to me when I read it, that's why I had to ask. Thanks for your input!

Comment: "nowadays the pimpl idiom is avoided". Isn't that a bit too generalized? Consider shared libraries where you want/need binary compatibility. I think it's still the way to go there. See Qt for example.

Comment: @Ignitor: I tried to be as careful as I could. Obviously, type erasure is a common requirement, and pImpl has its usecases. But perhaps it shouldn't be your first pattern to apply when encountering complexity.